# malloc + fgets dynamic allocation

Tags: c, malloc, fgets

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    char *tmp, *tmp2, *user, *pass, *line;
    printf("Inserire utente: "); scanf("%ms", &user); /* scanf %ms alloca dinamicamente la memoria */
    printf("Inserire password: "); scanf("%ms", &pass);
    line = malloc((strlen(user)+strlen(pass)) * sizeof(char)); /* DUBBIOOOOOOOOOO */
    fp = fopen("/home/pol/auth.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Errore apertura file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fgets(line, /* E QUI?? */ , fp);
        tmp = strtok(line, " ");
        tmp2 = strtok(NULL, "\n"); /* con fgets ultimo carattere è \n (se pwd=12 => 12\n) quindi devo tagliare prima di \n */
        if((strcmp(tmp,user) == 0) && (strcmp(tmp2,pass) == 0)){
            printf("USER: %s - PASS: %s\n", tmp, tmp2);
            free(user);
            free(pass);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        else{
            printf("Utente o password errati o non presenti nel DB\n");
            free(user);
            free(pass);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would like to know if:

1. it is correct to write into `fgets` the value `sizeof(line)` or not. My doubt is that `line` contain a pointer so it is always 4 or 8 bytes...
2. `line` is right allocated?

Comment: Yes but no, and no. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Actually, "No", "Yes" and "Yes"? ;)  And no, I'm not sure what he's trying to achieve here, either ;)

Comment: i want to dynamic allocate chars for user and for pass. then i want to allocate into line the sum of user+pass :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, sizeof(line) will return the size of the pointer. What you really want to do is just

   ```
   size_t size_required = strlen(user) + strlen(pass) + 1; /* Don't forget about \0! */
   ```

   And then just use that size as the size of line. (BTW: your code does not free line.)

   **Edit:** Actually, since you ultimately want to read there user + password + 2 token separators searched for by strtok, you want to add extra 3 characters: 1 for terminating \0, 1 for first separator ' ', and 1 for next separator '\n'. So that should be:

   ```
   size_t size_required = strlen(user) + strlen(pass) + 3; /* Don't forget about \0! */
   ```
2. You should remember, that m specifier for dynamic allocation is a non-standard extension. It won't work on some systems. And you should release `user` and `pass` **only** if their scanf calls return positive value (as in: if they succeed).
3. Allocation of `line` is incorrect: you allocate one character too few, so terminating \0 character won't fit (see above). Note that `strlen` returns string size *excluding* the terminating \0 character.

   Additionally, `sizeof(char)` is pointless. The standard guarantees that `sizeof(char)` is exactly 1 (because `sizeof` does not really return number of bytes, but number of chars required to cover bit representation of an argument).
4. **BONUS** You should check `tmp` and `tmp2` for `NULL`, just in case. Calling `strcmp` on `NULL` argument will cause segmentation fault. This is **important**: if a line read contains user+password longer than provided earlier, a token separator will not be read by fgets, and strtok, unable to find, for example, final '\n' character, *will* return NULL.

Comment: should your code be +2?? because i have 2 strings so 2 '\0' :)

Comment: You have 2 strings, but ultimately you'll read only 1 there, right? ;) fgets will read at most n-1 characters, and add that final last *one* terminating character. Then again, you want to read it with token separators, so you should probably use +3 (\0 + ' ' + '\n'). I've updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: Is it correct to write into fgets the value sizeof(line)?

A: No :)

Because, as you said, it's only 4 (or 8) bytes.

I'm not at all sure what you're trying to do.  Perhaps something like this?

```
#define MAXLINE 80

char *user, *pass, line[MAXLINE];
scanf ("%s", line);
user = malloc(strlen(line)+1);
strcpy (user, line);
...
```

Comment: i want to dynamic allocate chars for user and for pass. then i want to allocate into line the sum of user+pass :)